# partition not available after resize using gparted. how to recover it?

Tags: partitioning, gparted, hard-drive-recovery

I ran into a problem with my HDD.

I tried to make some space for my linux partition using gparted and I resized one of my NTFS partitions. Unfortunately, the operation didn't succeed and my partition is now inaccessible (when I try to open it from windows I get that popup menu that tells me that's not formatted).

Is there any way I can recover my partition and its data ?

I searched for this problem and found that [testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) might be a solution for this, but I don't know how to use it. After I analyzed the hard drive using this application, it says that the partition has some errors (Invalid NTFS or EXFAT boot or something like that) but then I'm stucked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem.

I used `ntfsfix` in ubuntu to fix the partition and then `chkdsk` in windows and my partition is back.