# Lost data after incomplete resize operation on a partition

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, gparted

Prior to the resize operation I had three partitions on the drive. Let's call them A, B and C (in order). First I will put in the facts:

1. Partition B was small in size and the data on it was no longer required by me.
2. So, I wanted to delete partition B and resize C so that I would have more space in it

I used GParted on my Ubuntu 12.04 machine and started the resize operation. I had to leave on a trip before the operation could finish (and this was after 10 hours had already elapsed since I started it). I hibernated my computer in the hope that I could resume the operation once I would have time for it.

When I switched on my computer, the hibernation did not take place. I freaked out and checked my HDD but was relieved to see that all the data was in place. After a few months of usage I have come to realize that a lot of my files have gotten interchanged and I am not able to access few of them. Sometimes when I play a video, some other audio starts playing.

It would be of real help to me if I can get my files properly mapped out like before. I hope someone would be able to help me out here.

*Note: The HDD in context to this question is a 1TB External HDD by Seagate.*

## Update

The filesystem in question is NTFS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [partition not available after resize using gparted. how to recover it?](http://superuser.com/questions/381149/partition-not-available-after-resize-using-gparted-how-to-recover-it) and/or [Gparted: during a partition resize my NTFS partition gone, how can i recover it?](http://superuser.com/q/181406/243198). (I may be wrong though… partition issues are pretty localized and dependant on the individual situation.)

Comment: @e-sushi The partition is usable but the data is misplaced. I saw that question and I can confirm that this is not a duplicate.

Comment: Giving you a +1 on the question (and a [tweet-shoutout](https://twitter.com/esushi_tm/status/447705033358848000)) to show you I surely don't want to step on anyone's toes. I'm merely pointing to the same kind of questions (*lost partitions while resizing with Gparted*) and their individually accepted answers as they might just fix your issue. Good luck! (Been there last week – “testdisk” and a bit of fiddling rescued me. Hope you'll be able to solve your issue too.)

Comment: Something that will certainly be helpful to know: *What **file-system** (Fat32, NTFS, Ext3, Ext4, …) is being used on the partition that's causing trouble?* Some are easy to restore/correct, others aren't. But knowing the file-system will definitely help narrow down the options/solutions.

Comment: @e-sushi The filesystem is NTFS.

Comment: After all this time any hope of doing a restoration of files has long past.